# Typo in Twitter 'real name'

Tags: bug, status-completed, twitter

The @stackui twitter account has "Exchange" spelt incorrectly in the account name.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration, I didn't know there was a stackui twitter stream :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out.  I've fixed the typo. (: